# Given rsync --link-dest, is it possible to determine which files were linked and which are new?

Tags: rsync

I'm using rsync `--link-dest` to preform a differential back up of my computer. After each backup, I'd like to save out a log of the new/changed files. Is this possible? If so, how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from the rsync mailing list:

Use `--itemize-changes`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another answer [from the mailing list](https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2011-October/026974.html). There's a script by Kevin Korb:

> If you want something you can run after the fact here is a tool I wrote
>   a while back that does a sort of diff across 2 --link-dest based backups:
>
> http://sanitarium.net/unix_stuff/rspaghetti_backup/diff_backup.pl.txt
>
> It will also tell you what files were not included in the newer backup
>   which --itemize-changes will not since it doesn't actually --delete
>   anything.  The program is written in perl so it should be easy enough to
>   tweak it if it doesn't do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For referance you can also compare using rsync to do a dryrun between hardlinked backup directories to see how they are changed.

```
rsync -aHin day_06_*/ day_05_* 2>&1 | grep -v '^\.d'
```

Shows files that are added, removed, or renamed//moved.

The later only happens if you have a re-linking program relinking files that were renamed/moved.  That can be important if you say had simply renamed a directory (rsync backup breaks the links in that case).